# Difference between event_params. key = session_engaged event_params.valu.int_value and event_params.value. string_value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have Bigquery connected to GA4 and I identified that the fields event_params.valu.int_value and event_params.value.string_value are filled in but I couldn't understand the difference because **I need to calculate engaged sessions and average engagement time.**

Using the **event_params.valu.int_value** field seems to be more correct as it is closer to the metric that the GA4 UI presents.

But I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right field.